# Showing the custom confirm window after canceling onbeforeunload module window in Chrome

Tags: javascript, window, dom-events

I have such situation:

1. The form is opened on tear-off window
2. There are unsaved changes
3. Window is being closed

In these circumstances, I need to display a standard module window,
[image]

and if the user clicks "Cancel", then custom confirm window should appear
[image]

But in Chrome the icon on the confirm window doesn't appear
[image]

On Firefox and on IE the icon appears  under the same circumstances.

Code of 'onbeforeunload' event:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // function where the confirm window is formed
    showConfirmWindow();

    return e.returnValue = window.getResource('', 'ex.unsaved_changes');
});
```

The path to the image is correct because this window is used not only here and the image is displayed. It is only in Chrome and only in such circumstances. I guess that Chrome saves resources because the window closes - so why pull up the icon. But maybe someone knows how to fix it for Chrome?

**Additional information:** if add timeout on 0 ms for function where the confirm window is formed -  the icon is shown

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // function where the confirm window is formed
    setTimeout(showConfirmWindow, 0);

    return e.returnValue = window.getResource('', 'ex.unsaved_changes');
});
```

But this is a bad decision.